# How powerful are the other League of Shadows members?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, batman-begins

Bruce Wayne is selected by Ra's al Ghul to be mentored, trained and to become a member of the League of Shadows during Batman Begins.

Maybe I misinterpreted it all, but I took it that all the members had to go through similar trials.

1. Do all members receive similar training?
2. Putting aside Batman's gadgets, would the other members be reasonable matches for Batman?
3. If most are lower level foot soldiers, how many Ducard/Bane/Bruce level members are there?

Comment: As far as I can remember, they were training Bruce to *lead* them, not just to become a member. Presumably this required much more rigorous training.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Bruce Wayne was a class above the average League of Shadows member. In Batman Begins Ra's Al Ghul says this:

> I took away your fear, and I showed you a path.
>   **You were my greatest student.**
>   It should be you standing by my side,
>   saving the world.

Shortly after that Batman confronts Ra's while he and his men are loading the train.

> **Batman** - I can't beat two of your pawns?
>   **Ra's** - As you wish.

Batman knew he could easily defeat two members of the League of Shadows on his own, and he goes on to take out four at once.

...

Additionally the Wikipedia article on the [League of Assassins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/League_of_Assassins) (the original name) claims:

> Ra's al Ghul (under the name Ducard) trains Bruce Wayne (Christian Bale) for an unspecified period of time **until he could best any of the League in single combat**.

Although I'm not sure how they came to that conclusion, as Bruce Wayne is only ever shown to spar with Ducard.

Comment: Perhaps Ducard spared with everyone else and they applied (slightly flawed) a->b logic

Answer (score 0):

The top three are the most powerful as they where trained to lead the rest of the league to war against the antagonist.  So they had to have the most difficult training, but batman would be able to beat any other member of the "league of shadows" as he was trained to be at the front of the battles.